# install k-medoids library - cannot find mpi.h

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, mpi

I tried to install [K-Medoids](https://github.com/e-dang/K-Medoids) in linux but it cannot find MPI. when I make it says:

```
/home/user01/App/K-Medoids/include/hpkmedoids/utils/utils.hpp:3:10: fatal error: mpi.h: No such file or directory
    3 | #include <mpi.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/hpkmedoids.dir/build.make:121: src/CMakeFiles/hpkmedoids.dir/types/distance_matrix.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1279: src/CMakeFiles/hpkmedoids.dir/all] Error 2
```

MPI is installed and I can compile files with mpicc and mpic++ but it cannot find that. can anyone help?

Comment: are you sure `cmake` is using `mpic++` instead of the `g++` compiler?

Comment: I think it is the problem but I cannot find g++ or gcc in cmake file to replace! @GillesGouaillardet

Comment: try `cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=mpic++ ...` (best from an empty directory) and then `make`

Comment: Hero of My Day @GillesGouaillardet

Comment: The **correct** project should work when use **default** C++ compiler (`g++`). Using `find_package(MPI)` the project is aware about compiler options needed for compile mpi program. These options are stored in variables like `MPI_CXX_INCLUDE_DIRS`, `MPI_CXX_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS`, etc. These variables are described in the [FindMPI documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindMPI.html). But given project ignores these variables, and uses only `MPI_LIBRARIES` for link: https://github.com/e-dang/K-Medoids/blob/master/src/CMakeLists.txt.